# ¿Es posible definir el tamaño máximo de un objeto string?

Tags: c++, string

Al igual que podemos hacer:

```
char cadena[20];
```

¿Se podría definir un string de un tamaño máximo definido?

Del estilo:

```
string cadena[20];
```

El objeto string es de la librería string de c++/c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Si declaras a `cadena` de la forma `std::string cadena[20];` estarás creando un arreglo de 20 objetos de tipo `std::string`. Será un vector de 20 cadenas de caracteres, tal y como [Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/19610/trauma) dijo.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, recuerda no realizar varias respuestas, debes realizar únicamente una, si deseas realizar cambios en tu respuesta, puedes modificarla, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Es posible definir el tamaño máximo de un objeto `std::string`?

No. El límite de tamaño de una cadena es la memoria que pueda ofrecerte el sistema operativo.

---

La definición `string cadena[20];` es una formación de veinte cadenas, no una cadena de veinte caracteres.

Si quieres una cadena de tamaño máximo prefijado, te la tendrás que programar:

```
template <typename char_t, unsigned tamanyo>
struct cadena_fija
{
    cadena_fija() = default;
    cadena_fija(const char_t (&formacion)[tamanyo]) {
        std::copy(formacion, formacion + tamanyo, datos);
    }
    cadena_fija(const cadena_fija &otra) :
        cadena_fija(otra.datos)
    {}

    template <typename c, unsigned t>
    friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &, const cadena_fija<c, t> &);
private:
    char_t datos[tamanyo]{};
};

template <typename char_t, unsigned tamanyo>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const cadena_fija<char_t, tamanyo> &cadena)
{
    for (const auto &c : cadena.datos)
    {
        if (!c)
            return o;
        o.put(c);
    }

    return o;
}
```

La implementación anterior es incompleta, pero [puede usarse así](https://tio.run/##lVLBboMwDD2Tr/A6iYJKq2lHSrnssn/YpsoKocsECQpmUlX118dMm7Z062GTEMJ@9vPj2bJp5hsp@/5eG1l1hYJM25acwjoXglTdVEicpG2jDNYK5Du6NSXQmVZvjCqAsEaztbngrk4SSCy4cl3qDxQ7EYzCKIYVFKrErqLlNSKtaclzQxSW1tUotTXxi6d/i4HJgpaKNJW22UbnkgTOnzA7qUmgQLJtzGP2NyddMhBachhDyvTjwiG7OLKIYLcXIrjlxtiIXASl08oUcJDpbWT@RjnmcZBl0TWSwC85GVNSDiFLb5z@5HEszBtzUHN2ZLdfCn7@u6S/KbM3pXnaExuERzQeFs1bAO8udmQZg9R3X2xkj3UJ0Z3kIAicos4ZsLylwC6ajiJ53JgYQRxpQ1CjNlH846JAlnxSk2db4YQb/XV0xP8zQPyevprpcGuHuid0KH2tH/DAA/r@S5YVbtp@zgwrOZs94jc):

```
int main()
{
    cadena_fija cf = "Hola";
    std::cout << cf << '\n';
    // Error, 'cf' sólo acepta 5 caracteres, no 9.
    cf = "Caracola";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

En general, **no** ... con ciertos matices.

Un `std::string` es un `typedef` de una clase mas general aún:

```
template< typename T, typename TRAITS = std::char_traits< T >, typename ALLOC = std::allocator< T > >
class string;

using string = std::basic_string< char >;
```

Esa clase base [`std::basic_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) usa ciertos elementos auxiliares, que se pueden utilizar para modificar su comportamiento: los parámetros de plantilla `TRAITS` y `ALLOC`.

El *jugar* con esos parámetros no es que permita hacer *maravillas*... pero nos puede ofrecer algo *con cierto parecido a lo que preguntas*. Digo parecido porque no es exactamente lo que quieres. Simplemente, nos lanzará una excepción si intentas que tu cadena sea mas grande de cierto tamaño prefijado:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template< typename T, size_t LIMIT > struct MyTrick : public std::allocator< T > {
  using std::allocator< T >::allocator;

  template< typename U > struct rebind {
    typedef MyTrick< U, LIMIT > other;
  };

  T *allocate( size_t len, const void *hint = 0 ) {
    if( len > LIMIT ) { throw std::bad_alloc( ); }

    return std::allocator< T >::allocate( len, hint );
  }
};

int main( ) {
  std::basic_string< char, std::char_traits< char >, MyTrick< char, 20 > > test;

  test = "1234567890";

  for( char idx = 0; idx < 9; ++idx ) {
    std::cout << test << '\n';
    test += ( idx + '0' );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Al ejecutarlo ...

> 1234567890
>   12345678900
>   123456789001
>   1234567890012
>   12345678900123
>   123456789001234
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>     what():  std::bad_alloc
>   Abortado

Con lo cual, podríamos capturar la excepción para realizar acciones en consecuencia.